# WPF - XAML Treeview to Generic.List binding

Tags: wpf, xml, binding, treeview, ilist

I am trying to bind an IList to a WPF TreeView in a hierarchal display. Here is my object:

```
public class TeamsTreeViewItem
 {
  public string DisplayValue { get; set; }
  public string KeyValue { get; set; }

  readonly List<TeamsTreeViewItem> children = new List<TeamsTreeViewItem> ();

  public IList<TeamsTreeViewItem> Children
  {
   get
   {
    return children;
   }
  }

  public override string ToString ()
  {
   return DisplayValue;
  }
 }
```

I don't know how many children a particular object will have, and the children might have children too.

I am fussing around with my HierarchialDataTemplate, but not being successful:

```
    <TreeView Canvas.Left="263" Canvas.Top="12" Height="200" Name="TeamTreeView" Width="120">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:TeamsTreeViewItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayValue}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayValue}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:TeamsTreeViewItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayValue}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should only have one HierarchicalDataTemplate as all your nodes are a TeamsTreeViewItem, otherwise how will WPF know which one to use? Also you need to bind ItemsSource to the Children collection: ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the ItemsSource to the children like so:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TeamsTreeViewItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayValue}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

I applied this DataTemplate based on the DataType, that way if the children are of the same type (TeamsTreeViewItem) is should automatically apply it to any item it finds of that type, even if it is a child, grandchild, or great great great .... grandchild.  Just make sure to include the namespace (denoted here as "local") that the TeamsTreeViewItem is defined in.